# Glide not showing the Image

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout

Hello I am trying to add a profile image in my application but it not showing the image I get this error I am also trying to add in user adapter it not showing also I can not the solve the problem thanks for answering thanks

**the error message**

```
2022-01-28 08:32:18.553 28556-28556/com.example.travelinstam I/ViewTarget: Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.
2022-01-28 08:32:18.568 28556-28556/com.example.travelinstam I/ViewTarget: Glide treats LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT as a request for an image the size of this device's screen dimensions. If you want to load the original image and are ok with the corresponding memory cost and OOMs (depending on the input size), use .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL). Otherwise, use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, set layout_width and layout_height to fixed dimension, or use .override() with fixed dimensions.
2022-01-28 08:32:18.742 28556-28556/com.example.travelinstam W/Glide: Load failed for gs://travelinstam2.appspot.com/placeholder.png with size [100x100]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
2022-01-28 08:32:18.785 28556-28556/com.example.travelinstam W/Glide: Load failed for gs://travelinstam2.appspot.com/placeholder.png with size [100x100]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

**here the my code**

```
    private void userInfo(){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(profileid);
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (getContext() == null){
                    return;
                }

                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                Glide.with(getContext()).load(user.getImageurl()).into(image_profile);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
                bio.setText(user.getBio());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

I use the hdodenhof:circleimageview version

```
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
```

here the my layout code

```
                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:id="@+id/image_profile"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried loading drawables?

Comment: Can you load this png in a normal ```ImageView```? Check it for damage.

Comment: What does `user.getImageurl()` return? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo yes sir I found the user.getImageurl not return I think when I write glide like this Glide.with(getContext()).load(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelinstam2.appspot.com/o/placeholder.png?alt=media&token=ead8ed60-7b52-491b-90cd-17162d659a20).into(image_profile);  it show but I dont know how to solve :D where I have to change

Comment: So is the imageUrl null?

Comment: in fact not I wrote in register activity like this hashMap.put("imageurl", "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelinstam2.appspot.com/o/placeholder.png?alt=media&token=ead8ed60-7b52-491b-90cd-17162d659a20"); in hashmap @AlexMamo

Comment: So is that the correct URL?

Comment: yes sir this is correct url @AlexMamo now I check the getImageurl it say this Method invocation 'getImageurl' may produce 'NullPointerException'

Comment: Please add the entire error message to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to open the resource from the link that I extracted from you log `gs://travelinstam2.appspot.com/placeholder.png` but it failed.

**Have you checked that the resource URL is correct and reachable?**

**Answer: According to our discussion in the comment section, the issue was with the URL provided to Glide.**

Comment: hashMap.put("imageurl", " https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/travelinstam2.appspot.com/o/placeholder.png?alt=media&token=ead8ed60-7b52-491b-90cd-17162d659a20 "); here I added on register activity

Comment: But the link provided to Glide is `gs://travelinstam2.appspot.com/placeholder.png`. You can see that in log. Try to provided a hardcoded link of image in order to test. Eg - https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80

Comment: I added and tryed again and give same error sir :D W/Glide: Load failed for gs://travelinstam2.appspot.com/placeholder.png with size [200x200]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource

Comment: For testing once use  `Glide.with(getContext()).load("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453728013993-6d66e9c9123a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8dmlld3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80").into(image_profile);`       in the onDataChange

Comment: yes it works sir but now when I tryed to edit profile the and trying to add new photo the app crash

Comment: Kindly mention the log here.

Comment: I think the error is in imageurl it dont return the link

Comment: Yes Your implementation part is correct, the issue is with the image URL. **Kindly mark my answer as correct answer if I was able to help you.**

Comment: done sir <3 I think image URL is correct but image url not return when I call user.getImageurl I also looked user model I wrote like this     public String getImageurl(){
        return imageurl;
    }

Comment: So now is your problem solved ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. *And kindly up vote the answer as it may help someone in future.*